# jqGrid 2 grids on page with different theme/skin

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, themes

I have a master/detail setup using jqGrid and jQuery. Is it possible to have the detail grid use a different theme/skin than the master grid?

I see a setting to change the images folder, but it looks to me like grid.css would have to be the same for the entire page. Has anyone tried? Or do you have any suggestions for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

[jqgrid-change-theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195374/jqgrid-change-theme) discusses having a jqgrid use a different theme than the rest of the site. You may be able to use the same principles to style one jqgrid differently from another.